# How to get a generic response from retrofit

Tags: java, android, generics, retrofit2

I have an issue, I use Retrofit2 to make three calls to a server to retrieve some jSon data. The issue I get is that I don't want to make three separate result classes for the response as the data will be the same apart from the list array type that holds the jSonArray.

e.g. 
`List<A>`
`List<B>`

So I made a class

```
public class Response<T> {

    @SerializedName("page")
    @Expose
    private int page;

    @SerializedName("results")
    @Expose
    private List<T> results = new ArrayList<T>();

    @SerializedName("total_results")
    @Expose
    private int totalResults;

    public int getPage()
    {
        return page;
    }

    public void setPage(int page){
        this.page = page;
    }

    public List<T> getResults(){
        return results;
    }

    public void setResults(List<T> results){
        this.results = results;
    }

    public int getTotalResults(){
        return totalResults;
    }

    public void setTotalResults(int totalResults){
        this.totalResults = totalResults;
    }
}
```

My question is how would i use this class with the `onResponse` method in Retrofit2?

I cant do:

```
@Override
public void onResponse(Call<Response<Movie>> call, Response<Response<Movie>> response) {
    List<Movie> movies = response.body().getResults();
}
```

Movie is just a class with getters and setters with the according fields having the @SerializedName annotation.

Comment: Fixed it by changing the Response to be the one I created instead of the default on from retrofit.

Comment: You did what now?